# Could not connect to Database: Access denied for user '***'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, plesk

I have a domain name with GoDaddy and a shared hosting plan with Plesk.

I have a development environment on my local computer using WAMP in where I've established a database connection locally.

Now that I've uploaded all the necessary files to Plesk (index.php, db_connect.php) I've created a new database through the Plesk control panel AND a default user for said database.  In my db_connect.php file I've set the host name to 'localhost', for db_user, the name of the user I created, for db_pass, the password I created, and finally the name of the database I've created.

When I go attempt to run my php script over the hosting server I keep getting the same error message:

Could not connect to Database: Access denied for user '***'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I've spent the last day and half reading the other posts related to this but to no avail.  I've also tried accessing the mysql root user through the SQL query panel on the Plesk phpmyadmin application but I keep getting a syntax error.  When I run queries like SHOW USER() and SHOW CURRENT_USER() all the information comes back to me correct but my access is still denied.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?  I am a beginner programmer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why was this question downvoted at all? Its a valid question. I too faced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem came from using localhost as the DB_HOST parameter.  Localhost is not correct in this situation.

The solution came from changing 'localhost' to the database server id which was found on my Plesk panel after clicking on the Database link and noting the 'database server' field for the database I was trying to connect to.  The format is similar to an IP address: xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx (where x = a number).  NOTE: the last 4 digits are a port number and are to be EXCLUDED when using them to connect to the database server.

The solution came from contacting the support team for Plesk which I found very late in my research (there's a tiny little blue sidebar on the far right of the screen that allows you to contact support - I didn't see this bar at first)

The information that support provided me related to the following link, where the same information can be provided.  (I didn't put two and two together!)
https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/39/viewing-your-database-details-with-shared-hosting-accounts?countrysite=ca